# Sine values being rational

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry, irrational-numbers

Can $$\sin r\pi $$ be rational if $r$ is irrational? Either a direct or existence proof is fine.

Comment: I was about to invoke [Niven's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NivensTheorem.html), but that assumes both $r$ and $\sin\;r\pi$ are rational.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Irrationality of Trigonometric Functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2476/irrationality-of-trigonometric-functions)

Comment: @Moron:  this one divides out the $\pi$, which eliminates some of the easy answers.

Comment: @Ross: Yes, but the answers there answer this too. Anyway,  I guess they are a bit different. I might have been too hasty to cast the dupe close vote.

Comment: I've created a new Wikipedia article titled [Niven's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem).  Two-and-a-half hours after I created it, I entered "Niven's theorem" into Google and that Wikipedia article was on the first page of results.  So contribute to it if you can.  Besides contributions _within_ the article, there's the matter of which other articles ought to link to it.  I've created three such links; if you think of others that should be there, you can add those too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As J. M. said, Niven's theorem does it.  There is some $r$ such that $\sin (r\pi) = \frac{1}{3}$  As $\sin (r\pi)$ is rational and not $0, \pm1, \pm \frac{1}{2}$, $r$ is not rational