# Drawing a triangle in a unit circle

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles, rational-numbers

This is a question that I derived for a long time ago. It asks if we draw a triangle in a unit circle does all arc lengths $(\alpha ,\beta ,\theta)$ and sides of triangle $(a,b,c)$ can be rational numbers? Intuitively I believe that the rationality does not hold but I can't derive a proof. Do you have any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\alpha + \beta + \theta = 2 \pi$, so they can't all be rational.

---

You might want to write the arc lengths as $\alpha \pi, \beta \pi, \theta \pi$, in which case $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 2$, and it gets slightly more interesting.

The answer is still no.

(WLOG, we have $0 \leq \alpha, \beta, \gamma \leq 2$.) This arises because $a= 2| \sin \frac{\alpha\pi}{2}|$, which is [rational if and only if](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87756/when-is-sinx-rational) $\frac{\alpha}{2} \in \{ 0, \frac{1}{6} ,\frac{1}{2}, \frac{5}{6}, 1\} $. This is known as [Niven's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NivensTheorem.html).

The only way to get $\frac{\alpha}{2} + \frac {\beta}{2} + \frac{\gamma}{2} = 1$ is then to require that $\alpha\beta\gamma=0$ (slight checking involved), which is the degenerate cases (that I'm ignoring). These cases correspond to either having a point on the circumference, or a chord of the circle.

Comment: Can you elaborate on th esecond "no"? After all there is the degenerate case with $a=b=2$, $c=0$.

Comment: @newzad I think we can both agree that $\pi$ and $1/\pi$ are irrational, but is $\pi\cdot1/\pi$? ;-)

Comment: Imagine $\alpha=k_12\pi$,$\beta=k_22\pi$,$\theta=k_32\pi$ and $k_1+k_2+k_3=1$ but $\alpha,\beta,\theta$ are rational.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I've added it in, and stated why we get the degenerate cases (of which there are a few more consisting of chords).

Comment: @oldrinb: $\pi$ and $1/\pi$... where's the love for $\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: @newzad With this change, I've answered your question in my second part.