# Show that $\sin 10^\circ$ is irrational

Tags: trigonometry

So, this is the problem I am working on.

Show that $\sin 10^\circ$ is irrational.

The solution to the problem is $$1/2 = \sin 30^\circ = 3 \sin 10^\circ - 4\sin^3 10^\circ .$$
Let $$x = 2\sin 10^\circ.$$

Then we have, $$x^3 - 3x + 1 = 0.$$ 
And, we have to work on this to find out the roots. But, what I don't understand is that why do I have to subtract $4\sin^3 10^\circ$ from $3\sin 10^\circ$. And,  how did they come up with $x^3 - 3x+1 = 0?$ I am confused. Can someone please explain this in details and is there any other way we can do this problem?

Comment: Sorry my bad. $1/2 = sin 30^\circ$

Comment: @user136442 Do you know that $\sin(3\alpha)=3\sin(\alpha)-4(\sin(\alpha))^3$, for all $\alpha \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: Sorry. Must've forgotten.

Comment: @user136442 It is likely, by reading the proposed solution, that that identity is a prerequisite for the problem. I suggest you assume it as true for the purpose of this problem.

Comment: This question is related to, but in no way is a duplicate of, [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/87756).

Comment: You can prove this in one line using Niven's Theorem:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**identity:** $\sin(3a)=3\sin(a)-4\sin^3(a)$ By using this identity,

$$1/2 = \sin 30^\circ = 3 \sin 10^\circ - 4\sin^3 10^\circ$$

$$1=2\sin 30^\circ = 6 \sin 10^\circ - 8\sin^3 10^\circ$$ Then if you set $x=2\sin(10)$ you will get $$x^3 - 3x+1 = 0.$$

Comment: By the way I assumed that you reached the conlusion. If not, set $x=t-1$ in above equation then you will get $t^3-3t^2+3$ by Einstain creteria, it has no rational roots.

Comment: Yes, I didn't find any integer root here.

Comment: @user136422: it also works and easier.

Comment: Yep.Sometimes I just need some handholding, that's all :-)

Comment: @user136422: me, too :)

Answer (score 3):

mesel's answer about why $2\sin(10^\circ)$ satisfies $x^3-3x+1=0$ is very good.

Let's answer the question about why $x^3-3x+1=0$ implies $x$ is irrational. In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/309071), it is shown that if $x^3-3x+1=0$ has a rational root, then that root must be an integer.

Suppose that $|x|\ge2$, then dividing by $x^3$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
1
&=\left|\,\frac3{x^2}-\frac1{x^3}\,\right|\\
&\le\frac34+\frac18\\
&=\frac78
\end{align}
$$
Thus, there can be no solutions for $|x|\ge2$.

Simply checking $\{-1,0,1\}$, we see there are no integer solutions. Therefore, any solution to $x^3-3x+1=0$ is irrational.

Comment: Really make sense.

Comment: Why not just say that by the rational root theorem, if there is a rational root it must be $\pm 1$?

Comment: Because there are many paths that lead to the same destination. I chose a different path.