# On the angular distribution of primitive Pythagorean triples

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

Suppose $f\, : \, \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ is defined by $$f(x,y) = \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right),$$
and set $P\subset \mathbb{Z}^2$ to be the set 
$$P = \left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\, \left|\, \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\in\mathbb{N}, \gcd\left(x,y,\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)=1\right.\right\}$$ (using the convention that $\mathbb{N}$ does not include $0$; i.e., the set of all $(x,y)$, with $x>0$, $y>0$, integers, so that $\left(x,y,\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)$ forms a primitive Pythagorean triple).

Define $\Omega_f$ to be the restriction of $f$ to $P$ (or the image of $P$ under $f$).

If $C = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \mid x> 0,y> 0, x^2+y^2=1\}$ is the segment of the unit circle lying in the first quadrant, and $C_f = \Omega_f \cap C$, then is $C_f \subset C$ dense?

Relevant things I have considered:

1. There are (countably) infinitely many primitive Pythagorean triples, but this doesn't say anything about their distribution in angle.
2. Equivalently, set $C = \{(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid 0< \theta < \pi/2\}$ (note this is the same set as $C$ above). Is the set $\{(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))\in \mathbb{R}^2\mid 0<\theta<\pi/2, \cos(\theta)\in\mathbb{Q},\sin(\theta)\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ dense as a subset of $C$?
3. Equivalently, let $P$ be as above. If we set $\theta(x,y) = \arctan(y/x)$, is $\text{image}(\theta|_P) \subset (0,\pi/2)$ dense (i.e., is the image of the restriction of $\theta$ to the set $P$ dense as a subset of $(0,\pi/2)$?
4. I do know that the image of a dense subset under a continuous surjection is itself dense, but I'm not sure how/if that is relevant.

---

Hope this isn't something that's already been addressed on MSE, or something that is trivially easy, but I have not been able to find a proof (or confirm whether one exists).

Comment: $P$ is not dense, so $\Omega_f$ cannot be dense.

Comment: @Pockets I assume OP means that $f(P)$ is dense in the unit circle.

Comment: @Travis, That's exactly what I mean (or at least the portion of the unit circle in the first quadrant).

Comment: Yes, the points with rational coordinates are dense on the unit circle.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you for the response. Is the proof more or less based on density of $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$? Or is there another proof I should be looking for?

Comment: @NicholasStull:  Consider the lines with rational slopes $m$ that pass through $(-1,0)$ (say). It is not hard to show such a line meets the unit circle at another rational point, and it is reasonably clear by continuity that these second meeting points are dense on the unit circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\ell_m$ be the line with slope $m$ that passes through the point $(-1,0)$.

Let $P_m=(x_m,y_m)$ be the second meeting point of $\ell_m$ with the unit circle. It is reasonably clear by continuity the set of second meeting points  as $m$ ranges over the **rationals** is dense on the unit circle.

The line $\ell_m$ has equation $y=m(x+1)$. Substituting in the equation of the unit circle, we get $x^2+m^2(x+1)^2=1$, which expands to
$$(1+m^2)x^2+2m^2 x+m^2-1=0.$$
One root of this quadratic is $-1$, and the product of the roots is $\frac{m^2-1}{m^2+1}$, so the other root is $x_m=\frac{1-m^2}{1+m^2}$. In particular, $x_m$ is rational. Substituting in $y=m(x+1)$ we find that $y_m=\frac{2m}{1+m^2}$,  also rational.

For actual Pythagorean triples, we use rational $m$ with $0\lt m\lt \frac{\pi}{4}$, and obtained denseness on the first-quadrant part of the unit circle.

Comment: That's exactly what I was after. Thank you very much. I couldn't think of how one would go about it, but this is rather elegant in its simplicity.

Comment: @NicholasStull: It gives a *rational parametrization* of the rational points on the unit circle. You can recognize that the ordered pair $(x_m,y_m)$, as described in terms of $m$, is close to the standard description of the (primitive) Pythagorean triples.

Comment: Does this address the questions about $f(P)$ (the set of primitive Pythagorean triples projected on the unit circle)?

Comment: @robjohn: Primitive or not primitive makes no difference. The argument shows we have denseness on the unit quarter-circle. As a consequence, the $x$-coordinates and $y$-coordinates are dense on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Okay, I am just missing where the Pythagorean triples come in (primitive or not).

Comment: @robjohn:  Every rational point on (open) quarter-circle comes from a Pythagorean triple (and conversely), a unique one if  we specify primitive.

Comment: Never mind. I see. I missed that the lines were through $(-1,0)$ and so you were using the standard $(m^2-n^2,2mn,m^2+n^2)$ Pythagorean Triangles. (+1) However, this might be confusing to others as well. Furthermore, did you mean $0\lt m\lt 1$

Answer (score 1):

If $p^2+q^2=r^2$ and $\tan(x)=\frac pq$, then $\sin(x)=\frac pr$ and $\cos(x)=\frac qr$. [Niven's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven's_theorem), which is proven in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/87768), says that if $x\in\mathbb{Q}\pi$ and $\sin(x)\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $\sin(x)\in\left\{0,\pm\frac12,\pm1\right\}$. Since both $\sin(x)\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $\cos(x)\in\mathbb{Q}$, we must have that $\sin(x),\cos(x)\in\left\{0,\pm1\right\}$.

Thus, if $p^2+q^2=r^2$ and $\arg(p+iq)\in\mathbb{Q}\pi$, then $pq=0$. Thus,
$$
\arg\left(\frac{4+3i}5\right)\not\in\mathbb{Q}\pi
$$
Therefore, we can find an $m,n$ so that $m\arg\left(\frac{4+3i}5\right)+n2\pi$ is arbitrarily close to $0$. This means that
$$
\left\{\left(\frac{4+3i}5\right)^n:n\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}
$$
is dense (and uniformly distributed) in the unit circle. The same can be done for any other non-trivial Pythagorean Triple.

Therefore,
$$
\left\{\frac{p+iq}r:p^2+q^2=r^2\text{ and }p,q,r\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}
$$
is dense and uniformly distributed in the unit circle.

In terms of the question, $f(P)$ is dense and uniformly distributed in the unit circle.