# When is $\sin x$ an algebraic number and when is it non-algebraic?

Tags: calculus, number-theory, trigonometry

> Show that if $x$ is rational, then $\sin x$ is algebraic number when $x$ is in degrees and $\sin x$ is non algebraic when $x$ is in radians.

Details: so we have $\sin(p/q)$ is algebraic when $p/q$ is in degrees, that is what my book says. of course $\sin (30^{\circ})$, $\sin 45^{\circ}$, $\sin 90^{\circ}$, and halves of them is algebraic. but I'm not so sure about $\sin(1^{\circ})$.

Also is this is an existence proof or is there actually a way to show the full radical solution.

One way to get this started is change degrees to radians. x deg = pi/180 * x radian. 
So if x = p/q, then sin (p/q deg) = sin ( pi/180 * p/q rad). Therefore without loss of generality the question is show sin (pi*m/n rad) is algebraic. and then show sin (m/n rad) is non-algebraic.

Comment: For the second part you'll also need to assume $x\ne0$.

Comment: Claim is false: $\sin 0^{\circ}$ and $\sin 0$ (in radians) are both algebraic.

Comment: Hint for the first part: Instead of considering $\sin(\frac{\pi}{180}x)$, view it as the real part of $z=-ie^{\frac{\pi}{180}xi}$ and consider $z^{180q}$ to see that $z$ is algebraic. Then the sine, being $\frac{z}{2}+\frac{\bar z}{2}$, is also algebraic, because the algebraic numbers are closed under addition.

Comment: You may be interested in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94478/sin-1-circ-is-irrational-but-how-do-i-prove-it-in-a-slick-way-and-tan1) and Hardy's comment there about Niven's Theorems and some links. Ofcourse, this comes for free with enlightening answers from various others.

Answer (score 11):

$\sin\left(\frac{p}{q}\pi\right)=\sin\left(\frac{p}{q}180^\circ\right)$
is always algebraic for $\frac{p}{q}\in\mathbb{Q}$:
Let
$$
\alpha=e^{\frac{i\pi}{q}}=\cos\frac{\pi}{q}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{q}.
$$
Then $\alpha^q+1=0$, i.e. $\alpha$ is an (algebraic)
$2q^\text{th}$ root of unity, i.e. it is a root of $x^{2q}-1$.
Hence, so is its power $\alpha^p$ and reciprocal/conjugate power,
which for $p$ an $q$ in lowest terms are roots of $x^q-(-1)^p=0$.
Therefore, so too are
$$
\cos\frac{p\pi}{q}=\frac{\alpha^p+\alpha^{-p}}{2}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\sin\frac{p\pi}{q}=\frac{\alpha^p-\alpha^{-p}}{2i},
$$
by the closure of the algebraic numbers as a field.

Ivan Niven gives a nice proof at least that $\sin x$
is [irrational](http://books.google.ch/books?id=ov-IlIEo47cC&pg=PA15&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4) for (nonzero) rational $x$.
As @Aryabhata points out, the
[Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)
gives us that these values of $\sin$ and $\cos$
are transcendental (non-algebraic),
by using the fact that the field extension $L/K$
of $L=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$
over $K=\mathbb{Q}$
has [transcendence degree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendence_degree) 1.

Comment: Why is a^q +1 = 0 algebraic? I thought algebraic number means it is the root of a polynomial with integer coefficients. this might be beyond the scope of my knowledge. But your alpha is a root of unity , and is a complex number.

Comment: I edited my post. Is it clear now? $\alpha$ is a root of $x^q+1=0$ and hence also $x^{2q}-1=0$.

Comment: @bob: The relevant polynomial is $x^q + 1$, not $\alpha^q + 1$. As $\alpha$ is a root, and $sin$ can be expressed linearly in $\alpha$, we have that $sin$ is algebraic at that value too.

Answer (score 4):

[Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) implies that for $\alpha$ non-zero algebraic, $\sin \alpha$ is transcendental.

Comment: well sin (pi*x) , pi*x is not algebraic since pi is not algebraic. That is sufficient to prove sin(pi*x) is algebraic? Are you saying that for any 'a' transcendental sin(a) is algebraic? I should qualify 'a' to be a real transcendental. so is sin(e) algebraic?

Comment: @bobthornton: No, I am saying for any $a$ algebraic (and non-zero), $\sin a$ is transcendental. The other portion of your question was answered by bgins. No clue when $a$ is transcendental (except rational multiples of $\pi$).