# sine of non-zero algebraic number is necessarily transcendental

Tags: number-theory, transcendental-numbers

How can we prove or disprove that:
$$\forall x \in \mathbb{A}\setminus\{0\} \implies \sin{x} \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{A}$$
Is that holds for other trig functions?

Comment: Consider $\text{Image}(\sin x) \cap \mathbb{A} = \{-1,0,1\}$. Therefore, $x \in \mathbb{A}\setminus \{0\}\text{ and }\sin x \in \mathbb{R}\cap \mathbb{A}$ if and only if $\dfrac{\pi}{2} \in \mathbb{A}$ or $-\dfrac{\pi}{2}\in \mathbb{A}$.

Comment: $\text{Image}(\sin{x}) = [-1, 1]$, no? But $\frac{1}{2} \in  [-1, 1]$ and $\frac{1}{2} \in  \mathbb{A}$

Comment: Lindemann-Weierstrass Theorem. See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112938/when-is-sin-x-an-algebraic-number-and-when-is-it-non-algebraic)

Comment: @Taylor According to this link, the only rational numbers that are algebraic integers are integers: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_integer)

Answer (score 1):

The Hermite-Lindemann (Transcendence) Theorem (which is deep) is that if $a_1,..,a_n$ are $n$ distinct algebraic numbers and $A_1,..., A_n$ are non-$0$ algebraic, then $\sum_{j=1}^nA_je^{a_j}\ne 0.$

Equivalently, if $a_1,...,a_m$ are $m$ distinct algebraics and (in  case $m=1$) not all $a_j=0,$ and if $A_1,..., A_m$ are non-$0$ algebraic, then $\sum_{j=1}^mA_je^{a_j}$ is transcendental.

If $0\ne t\in A$ then with $a_1=it,\,a_2=-it,$ and $A_1=1=-A_2,$ we have $2i\sin t=A_1e^{a_1}+A_2e^{a_2}\not \in A,$ so $\sin t \not \in A.$

Answer (score 0):

With less than Lindemann-Weierstrass: only Lindemann. If $\sin(x)\in\overline{\mathbb Q}$, $i\cos(x)$ is too. So is $e^{ix}$.