# Formula for $\sin(n\theta)$ in terms of $\sin(\theta)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I am looking for a formula for $\sin(n\theta)$ in terms of $\sin(\theta)$, where $n \in \Bbb R$. [The multiple-angle formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Multiple-angle_and_half-angle_formulae) only seems to work with integers, because of the $\prod$-function. Is there a generalization?

Comment: Probably $n\in\Bbb Q$ would give multiple/fractional angle type formulas. How would you expand $\sin(\sqrt 2\theta)$, which [is transcendental](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112938/when-is-sin-x-an-algebraic-number-and-when-is-it-non-algebraic), for example?

Comment: Why not just use de Moivre's theorem?

Comment: @ChrisLewis How would it be helpful?

Comment: $\sin{n\theta}=\Im \left(\sqrt{1-\sin^2 {\theta}}+i \sin{\theta}\right)^n$, although you have to be careful about the sign of the square root (so you'd get a piecewise defined function).

Comment: I realise this is the obvious answer, but I'm wondering why it wouldn't be an answer to your question as it's worded. As @TymaGaidash says, you're going to run into difficulties with irrational values of $n$ with any other formulation.

Comment: A even less helpful answer would be $\sin\left(n\,\sin^{-1}(\sin \theta)\right)$

Comment: @ChrisLewis What is the function $\displaystyle \mathfrak J(x)$ called? I had no idea about this, so it very well might be the obvious answer, I am just not knowledgeable about this :)

Comment: It just means the imaginary part. You can avoid it altogether if you instead write $$\sin{n\theta}=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\left(\sqrt{1-\sin^2 {\theta}}+i \sin{\theta}\right)^n-\left(\sqrt{1-\sin^2 {\theta}}-i \sin{\theta}\right)^n\right)$$ but I'm not sure how useful this is for your particular question

Comment: @ChrisLewis Well, I am a bit confused as to how the ratio of the opposite to the hypotenuse could be a complex number. Is there a way to convert it into a real number?

Comment: The imaginary part of a complex number *is* real (for instance, the imaginary part of $2+3i$ is $3$). Have you come across $e^{i\theta}=\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta}$ before? If not, the references I made to de Moivre's theorem won't make much sense.

Comment: @ChrisLewis I have come across that equation yes, though I don't remember the proof. I thought the imaginary part of $2 + 3i$ would be $3i$, but I see now its just the multiple of $i$. However, the equation for $\sin n\theta$ you showed has multiple $i$'s, so taking the imaginary part would mean factoring a little, in order to get one factor of $i$, and then just removing it?

Comment: @ChrisLewis Or is there perhaps some cancelling out between the $i$ in the denominator and the $i$'s in the numerator?

Comment: The $i$ cancels out, as you say. It's similar to the formula $\sin{\theta}=\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}\right)$

Comment: @ChrisLewis Okay, thanks :) If you make this into an answer (linking to a proof of it, or proving it yourself), I will accept it.  Feel free to add any other formulas. I don't know yet if I will be able to use this formula  to  help me with my current problem, so any other formulas are welcome as well.

Comment: @ChrisLewis I just read De Moivre's formula doesn't hold for integer $n$'s. If your formula is derived from De Moivre's formula, how is it able to hold for non-integers?

Comment: I think you missed my earlier point that I *didn't* think this was a useful answer!! (I think, by the way, there are extensions to de Moivre you can use for non integer powers, but it gets messy). You mention you have a current problem you're working on, can you share that?

Comment: @ChrisLewis Since it doesn't work for non-integers, it isn't a useless answer; instead, it isn't an answer at all to my question. The problem I was working on was wanting to take the expression $c\arcsin(a) + \arcsin(b)$ and turn it into $c\arcsin(a) + c\arcsin(f_{1/c}(b))$, where $f_z(x)$ is a function that takes $\sin(x)$ to $\sin(zx)$.

Comment: Read https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/st/De_Moivre_s_Theorem.html#:~:text=can%20be%20any%20real%20number%2C%20not%20just%20an%20integer.