# Showing $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{125}{12}\sqrt[10]{\frac{1 + x}{1 - x}} (x^2 - x) \, dx = \phi\pi$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

While exploring possible applications for this *[new trick](https://geometriadominicana.blogspot.com/2024/03/integration-using-some-euler-like.html)*, I stumbled upon an entire family of integrals that "always" yield $a\pi^n$, where $a$ is an algebraic number and $n$ is a natural number. The following integral captivated me greatly:

> $$\boxed{\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{125}{12}\sqrt[10]{\frac{1 + x}{1 - x}} (x^2 - x) \, dx = \color{red}{\phi}\color{blue}{\pi}}\tag{1}$$

The family:

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \left( \frac{1 + x}{1 - x} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} (x^2 - x) \, dx = 0$$

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \left( \frac{1 + x}{1 - x} \right)^{\frac{1}{4}} (x^2 - x) \, dx = \frac{\pi}{8\sqrt{2}}$$

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \left( \frac{1 + x}{1 - x} \right)^{\frac{1}{6}} (x^2 - x) \, dx = \frac{10\pi}{81}$$

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \left(\frac{1 + x}{1 - x}\right)^{\frac{1}{8}} (x^2 - x) \, dx = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{100}  \left(\frac{22787}{479}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}} \pi^2$$

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \left( \frac{1 + x}{1 - x} \right)^{\frac{1}{10}} (x^2 - x) \, dx = \frac{12}{125}\phi\pi$$

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \left( \frac{1 + x}{1 - x} \right)^{\frac{1}{12}} (x^2 - x) \, dx = \frac{15455288\pi}{94257441}$$

1. Do you know of other cases of integrals that yield $\phi\pi$ in a non-obvious manner?
2. The family seems to beg for a generalization. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Perhaps, you mean $a\pi$ where $a$ is algebraic. Every integral can be written as $a\pi$ for some real $a$. Also, in that case, the integral with $1/8$ is not $a\pi$, but rather $a\pi^2$.

Comment: @ultralegend5385: Thanks. I think I fixed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's concider
$$I(\alpha)=\int_{-1}^1\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^\alpha x(x-1)dx;\,\,-1<\alpha<2$$
Making the substitution $\frac{1+x}{1-x}=t$
$$I(\alpha)=4\int_0^\infty\frac{t^\alpha}{(1+t)^4}(1-t)dt$$
Making the substitution $x=\frac1{1+t}$
$$=4\int_0^1(1-x)^\alpha x^{2-\alpha}dx-4\int_0^1(1-x)^{\alpha+1}x^{1-\alpha}dx$$
Integrating the second term by parts
$$=4\frac{1-2\alpha}{2-\alpha}\int_0^1(1-x)^\alpha x^{2-\alpha}dx=4\frac{1-2\alpha}{2-\alpha}B\big(1+\alpha;3-\alpha\big)=\frac23\frac{1-2\alpha}{2-\alpha}\Gamma(1+\alpha)\Gamma(3-\alpha)$$
Using the Euler formula for Gamma-function
$$I(\alpha)=\frac23\frac{1-2\alpha}{2-\alpha}\alpha(2-\alpha)(1-\alpha)\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(1-\alpha)=\frac{2\pi}3\frac{\alpha(1-\alpha)(1-2\alpha)}{\sin\pi\alpha}$$
You can quickly check the answer, for example, at $\alpha=\frac16$ and get $\displaystyle\frac{10\pi}{3^4}$

Comment: This is elegant and beautiful. Thanks for posting this kind of answers. Cheers :-)

Comment: @Claude Leibovici , thank you for your kind words. Have a nice day!

Comment: (+1) Wow! Due to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/112947/818304), we can also see that when $\alpha$ is rational, the answer is $\pi$ times some algebraic number. But this also means that the answer in the original post is wrong (I manually checked that the answer given by the formula in this post does not match).

Comment: @ultralegend5385, yes, the answer is in general $\pi$ times some algebraic number. I have some doubt about the answer at $\alpha=\frac18$, but the answers at $\alpha=\frac12, \,\frac14,\,\frac16$ are correct

Comment: You are correct about my integral giving $\phi\pi$. That's incorrect. But the difference is [0.000000000000384581](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5B125%2C12%5DSurd%5BDivide%5B1%2Bx%2C1-x%5D%2C10%5D*%5C%2840%29Power%5Bx%2C2%5D-x%5C%2841%29%2C%7Bx%2C-1%2C1%7D%5D+-+%5C%2840%29golden+ratio%5C%2841%29%5C%2840%29pi%5C%2841%29&lang=es). I'm sorry, it was 2:00 a.m. and I got these results empirically. So the original integral is just *almost* $\phi\pi$.

Comment: I guess your answer is however correct, given that $\sin\frac\pi{10}=\frac{\sqrt 5-1}4$ :)   https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Csin%28%5Cpi%2F10%29