# How to write the complex number $z=-4-3i$ in polar form

Tags: complex-numbers

According to the triangle that is formed in the third quadrant we have to calculate $ \tan (\alpha) = \frac {3}{4} $.
How do I calculate the latter without using a calculator?

Comment: It is not duplicated, my problem is how to find arctan $arctan(\frac{3}{4})$ without calculator

Comment: See [here](https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-evaluate-sin-arctan-3-4-without-a-calculator) and similar links for how to find it without calculator. maybe, [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128514/solving-the-arctan-of-an-angle-radians-by-hand) is helpful, too.

Comment: $\because \tan a < 1$ then you can infer it will be less than $45 ^o$.  If you remember that $\tan 30^ o = 0.57$ Then also you can pinpoint it within 15 degrees