# How to solve for the exact answer of a cubic equation with very complicated constant term? (in order to solve for $\sin(1^\circ)$)

Tags: trigonometry, cubics

I am trying to figure out the exact value of $\sin(1^\circ)$ and $\cos(1^\circ)$ so that I am able to get the exact value of every integral sine and cosine. The list of formulas that we need are:
$$\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\sin\alpha\cdot\cos\beta+\cos\alpha\cdot\sin\beta$$
$$\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\cos\alpha\cdot\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\cdot\sin\beta$$
$$\sin(2\alpha)=2\sin\alpha\cdot\cos\alpha$$
$$\cos(2\alpha)=\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha$$
$$\sin30^\circ=\frac{1}{2},~\cos30^\circ=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},~\sin45^\circ=\cos45^\circ=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$
*My Current Progress:*

We'll need another formula for "triple" angle.
$$\sin(3\alpha)=\sin(2\alpha+\alpha)=\sin2\alpha\cos\alpha+\cos2\alpha\sin\alpha$$
$$\sin(3\alpha)=2\sin\alpha\cos^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha\sin\alpha-\sin^3\alpha$$
$$\sin(3\alpha)=3\sin\alpha\cos^2\alpha-\sin^3\alpha$$
$$\sin(3\alpha)=3\sin\alpha(1-\sin^2\alpha)-\sin^3\alpha$$
$$\sin(3\alpha)=3\sin\alpha-4\sin^3\alpha$$
$$\cos(3\alpha)=\cos(2\alpha+\alpha)=\cos2\alpha\cos\alpha-\sin2\alpha\sin\alpha$$
$$\cos(3\alpha)=\cos^3\alpha-\sin^2\alpha\cos\alpha-2\sin^2\alpha\cos\alpha$$
$$\cos(3\alpha)=\cos^3\alpha-3\sin^2\alpha\cos\alpha$$
$$\cos(3\alpha)=\cos^3\alpha-3(1-\cos^2\alpha)\cos\alpha$$
$$\cos(3\alpha)=4\cos^3\alpha-3\cos\alpha$$
Since we want to calculate a very small angle, we want to calculate a bigger but still very small angle. The smallest angle that I can calculate directly that I think of is $3^\circ$ by subtracting $72^\circ$ from $75^\circ$.

Let's find $\sin 72^\circ$ and $\cos 72^\circ$ first. We need the value of $\sin18^\circ$ or $\cos18^\circ$ first because calculating $72^\circ$ is a bit hard.
$$\sin(36^\circ)=\cos(90^\circ-36^\circ)$$
$$\sin(2\cdot18^\circ)=\cos(3\cdot18^\circ)$$
$$2\sin18^\circ\cos18^\circ=4\cos^318^\circ-3\cos18^\circ$$
$$4\cos^318^\circ-3\cos18^\circ-2\sin18^\circ\cos18^\circ=0$$
$$\cos18^\circ(4\cos^218^\circ-2\sin18^\circ-3)=0$$
$$\textrm{Since }\cos18^\circ\neq0,~4\cos^218^\circ-2\sin18^\circ-3=0.$$
$$4-4\sin^218^\circ-2\sin18^\circ-3=0$$
$$4\sin^218^\circ+2\sin18^\circ-1=0$$
$$\sin18^\circ=\frac{-2\pm\sqrt{2^2+4\cdot4}}{8}$$
$$\sin18^\circ=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{4}$$
$$\textrm{Since }\sin^\circ>0,~\sin18^\circ=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{4}.$$
Therefore, $\cos72^\circ=\sin18^\circ=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{4}$ and $\sin 72^\circ=\sqrt{1-(\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{4})^2}=\frac{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}{4}$.
$$\sin75^\circ=\sin(30^\circ+45^\circ)=\sin30^\circ\cos45^\circ+\cos30^\circ\sin45^\circ=\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}}{4}$$
$$\cos75^\circ=\cos30^\circ\cos45^\circ-\sin30^\circ\sin45^\circ=\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}$$
Now we can calculate the values of $\sin 3^\circ$ and $\cos 3^\circ$.
$$\sin3^\circ=\sin75^\circ\cos72^\circ-\cos75^\circ\sin72^\circ$$
$$\sin3^\circ=\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}}{4}\cdot\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{4}-\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}{4}$$
$$\sin3^\circ=\frac{(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6})\cdot(-1+\sqrt{5})-(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2})\cdot\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}{16}$$
$$\cos3^\circ=\cos75^\circ\cos72^\circ+\sin75^\circ\sin72^\circ$$
$$\cos3^\circ=\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}\cdot\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}}{4}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}{4}$$
$$\cos3^\circ=\frac{(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2})\cdot(-1+\sqrt{5})+(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6})\cdot\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}{16}$$
I have checked with approximate values that these two values are correct.
$$\textrm{Let }x=\sin1^\circ\textrm{ and }y=\cos1^\circ$$
$$\sin3^\circ=3x-4x^3$$
$$\cos3^\circ=4y^3-3y$$
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
      \frac{(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6})\cdot(-1+\sqrt{5})-(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2})\cdot\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}{16}=3x-4x^3\\
      \frac{(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2})\cdot(-1+\sqrt{5})+(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6})\cdot\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}{16}=4y^3-3y\\
      x^2+y^2=1
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}
Here is where I got stuck. I can't solve a cubic function with this giant constant term. I have three equations (sin, cos, and sum of squares) that I can use. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can write the solutions [this way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano's_formula).

Comment: Related: ["Can we express $\sin1^\circ$ in a real closed, not repetitive, radical forms?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/227575/409).

Comment: @plop I thought $\sin 3^\circ$ is already complicated enough, but looking at that formula it's gonna get much worse. Is there a better way that we can simplify it a little bit more?

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Not all small problems have small solutions.

Comment: Tiny improvement, for what little it's worth: $(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6})\sqrt{10 + 2\sqrt{5}} = 2(1+\sqrt{3})\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}}$ and I kind of want to pull out a $\sqrt{5}$ as well because $-1+\sqrt{5}$ and $1+\sqrt{5}$ make me think there's more pattern I can't see yet.

Comment: @Interstigation: For what it's worth, your expression for $\sin 1^\circ$ matches [the one I give in the update to this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1541219/409), except that I factor-out a $\sqrt{2}$. I'm not saying that this form is the simplest possible, but I don't happen to know of any particular improvement. (If there is an improvement, it might help in pinning down the pattern in that answer.)

Comment: @Blue I see. There just can't be any *significant* improvements. That's probably the best  you can do starting with $3^\circ$

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Trigonometric constants expressed in real radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_constants_expressed_in_real_radicals) omits $1^\circ$.

Comment: @Somos It only has $1.5^\circ$ from what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment, of course you can solve for $x$ in the equation
$$ \frac{(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6})\cdot(-1+\sqrt{5})-(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2})\cdot\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}{16}=3x-4x^3. $$
It will just be an even much bigger and uglier expression.
And it will involve square roots of negative numbers at some point while you are evaluating it; this is unavoidable.
(See the answers to
[Can we express the value of $\sin 1^\circ$ without using the imaginary unit?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1885083/139123)
and
[Is it possible get an algebraic expression for $\sin 1^\circ$ that does not contain roots of negative values?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3090045/139123).)

But if you start with a larger angle than $3^\circ$ there are expressions that are not so ugly. Here is one that is very neat (albeit possibly a little cryptic at first) from
[The Sine of a Single Degree](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/awards/college.math.j.47.5.322.pdf)
by Travis Kowalski:
$$
\sin 1^\circ = \frac{\sqrt[90]{\sqrt{-1}} - \sqrt[90]{-\sqrt{-1}}}{2 \sqrt{-1}}
$$
where all the roots are principal roots.

Comment: Wow I like the second form! basically $\sin1^\circ=\frac{\sqrt[90]{i}-\sqrt[90]{-i}}{2i}$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$