# Justify that $\tan 1^\circ$ is an irrational number

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry, irrational-numbers

> Justify that $\tan 1^\circ$ is an irrational number.

I don't know how to go about it

Comment: I would think you're going to have to explain what $tg1^\circ$ is.  I wouldn't say it was a number, let alone guess what class of number it might be...

Comment: Do you mean $\tan1^\circ$ (`\tan1^\circ`)?

Comment: I imagine the OP is looking at $\tan(\pi/180)$ in radian.

Comment: See [$\sin 1^\circ$ is irrational but how do I prove it in a slick way? And $\tan(1^\circ)$ is .....](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94478/sin-1-circ-is-irrational-but-how-do-i-prove-it-in-a-slick-way-and-tan1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $t_k = \tan k^\circ$ for positive integer $k$.

Please note that for $k < 45$, $0 < t_k < 1\implies 1 - t_k^2 \ne 0$.

Consider what happens if $t_1$ is ratonal. By repeat application of [double-angle formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-angle_formulae) for tangent, we have

$$\begin{align} t_1 \in \mathbb{Q} \implies & t_2 = \frac{2t_1}{1-t_1^2} \in \mathbb{Q}
\implies  t_4 = \frac{2t_2}{1-t_2^2}\in \mathbb{Q}\\
\implies &t_8  = \frac{2t_4}{1-t_4^2}\in \mathbb{Q} \implies t_{16} = \frac{2t_8}{1-t_8^2}\in \mathbb{Q}\\
\implies &t_{32} = \frac{2t_{16}}{1 - t_{16}^2}\in \mathbb{Q}
\end{align}$$
Recall $\displaystyle\;\tan(\theta -\phi) = \frac{\tan\theta - \tan\phi}{1 + \tan\theta\tan\phi}\;$, this implies $\;t_{30} = \frac{t_{32} - t_2}{1 + t_{32}t_2} \in \mathbb{Q}$.
Since $t_{30} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ is irrational, this is impossible.

As a result, $\tan 1^\circ = t_1$ is irrational.

Comment: Congrats on 100k!

Comment: how do you know that $t_2 = \frac{2t_1}{1-t_1^2}$ ?

Comment: @vmahth1 this is [double angle formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-angle_formulae) for tangent $\tan(2\theta) = \frac{2\tan\theta}{1 - \tan^2\theta}$.

Comment: $t_30$ is this also a trigonometric formula? why not $t_{30} = \frac{2t_{15}}{1 - t_{15}^2}$?

Comment: @vmahth1 the formula for $t_{30}$ is the formula for subtraction of angle. You can also use $t_{30}=\frac{2t_{15}}{1−t_{15}^2}$ but then you need to justify why $t_{15} \in \mathbb{Q}$ (under the assumption $t_1 \in \mathbb{Q}$). Aside from double angle formula, you need to use subtraction/addition formula once.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a more algebraic approach not given in Minus One-Twelfth's link.  Let $c$ and $s$ denote $\cos 1^\circ$ and $\sin 1^\circ$, respectively.  We have
$$(c+is)^{180}=e^{\pi i}=-1,$$
so
$$\Im(c+is)^{180}=0.$$
That is
$$\sum_{k=1}^{90}(-1)^{k-1}\binom{180}{2k-1}s^{2k-1}c^{180-2k+1}=0.$$
Note that $s,c\ne 0$.  If $t$ is $\tan 1^\circ$, we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{90}(-1)^{k-1}\binom{180}{2k-1}t^{2(k-1)}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{90}(-1)^{k-1}\binom{180}{2k-1}s^{2k-1}c^{180-2k+1}}{sc^{179}}=0.$$

If $t$ is a rational number, then $t=\frac{p}{q}$ for some positive integers $p,q$ such that $\gcd(p,q)=1$.  By the rational root theorem, $p,q\mid180$, so we can write $t=\frac{n}{180}$ for some integer $n$.  Because $$\frac{\pi}{180}<\tan\frac{\pi}{180}<\frac{\tan(\pi/4)}{45}=\frac{1}{45},$$
where the first inequality is due to the inequality $\tan x>x$ for all $x\in(0,\pi/2)$, and the second inequality is true by convexity of $\tan$ on $(0,\pi/2)$.  However, this means 
$$\pi<n<4,$$
but this is a contradiction (no integers lie strictly between $\pi$ and $4$).  So $t=\tan 1^\circ$ cannot be rational.

Answer (score 2):

(Another way).Let $\sin(1)=x$. We have $\sin(15)=\dfrac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}}{2}$.
$$\sin(5(3))=5\sin(3)-20\sin^3(3)+16\sin^5(3)\\\sin(3)=3x-4x^3$$ Hence
$$5(3x-4x^3)-20(3x-4x^3)^3+16(3x-4x^3)^5=\dfrac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}}{2}$$
If $x$ were rational then $(3x-4x^3)^n$ were rational for all integer  $n$ so we would have $LHS$ rational and $RHS$ irrational, absurde.The irrationality of $\tan(1)$ follows.

Comment: How does the irrationality of $\tan 1^\circ$ follow from knowing that $\sin 1^\circ$ is irrational?

Comment: $\tan(x)=\dfrac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}}$. (Obviously keeping into account that $x$ is an irrational not "simple" as, for example $x=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}$(It is known that it is actually trascendental

Comment: This doesn't imply $\tan 1^\circ$ is irrational in my opinion.  How do you know that $x$ is not simple, and what does simple even mean?  Like, why can't $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3601}}$, which would mean $\tan 1^\circ=\frac{1}{60}$.  And what is known to be transcendental?  Certainly not $\sin 1^\circ$, or $\tan 1^\circ$.

Comment: You are right. I was confused with saying about trascendental. What is clear is that $x$ is root of a complicated polynomial and it is evident that it is algebraic. On the other hand, can you make rational the value $\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ for such a value of $x$? Impossible if the degree of $x$ is high greater than $2$.