# Rational multiples of $\pi/2$ whose sines are also rational

Tags: trigonometry, rational-numbers

Let $f(x)=\sin(x\frac{\pi}{2})$.
Let $R$ the set of $x$ such that :

- $0\le x\le 1$
- $x \in \mathbb Q$
- $f(x) \in \mathbb Q$

Hence, $0\in R$ as $f(0)=0$. $1\in R$ as f(1)=1. And $\frac{1}{3}\in R$ as $f(\frac{1}{3})=\frac{1}{2}$.

Are they any other elements of $R$ ? How to find them all ?

Thanks !

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15823/sine-values-being-rational

Comment: Is there a proof of Niven's theorem? I can't seem to find it on any of those sites or links...

Comment: Actually there is a Proof Sketch in the "Talk" section of the wikipedia article. Thanks